# Read all descendants of a single element

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml, xmldocument

I have a following XML file:

```
<data>
    <set1>
        <entry>Entry #1</entry>
        <entry>Entry #2</entry>
    </set1>
</data>
```

and I'm trying to read all the descendants of the SET element. Im not sure If I'm confusing terms like element and descendant, so Im just gonna stop using them for now :)

Here is the C# code that I use:

```
List<String> list = new List<String>();
XDocument xml = XDocument.Load("file.xml");

var desc = xml.Descendants("set1");
foreach (var entry in desc) {
    list.add(entry.Value);
    Console.Write("element: " + entry.Value);
}
```

But instead of two lines of console output "Entry #1" and "Entry #2" I only get one "Entry #1Entry #2". Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something Like :

```
 var desc = xd.Descendants("set1").Elements("entry");
```

Comment: @Tomáš'GunsBlazing'Frček Always Welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

Change to

```
var desc = xml.Descendants("set1").Descendants();
```

And also

```
Console.WriteLine
```

I just tried it and it works.

The error is that `Descendants("set1")` does not give you the descendants of `set1`. It gives you the xml's root descendants that are *called* `set1`.

As for the `Console.WriteLine` - it adds a newline at the end of what it writes.

Comment: It works, thank you, seems to me that using Elements() function with no argument should do the same as using the Descendants() function.

Comment: @Tomáš'GunsBlazing'Frček Not exactly. `Descendants` will give you nested descendants as well. In this case there are none. But try it with: `<entry><abc>Entry #2</abc></entry>` and see what happens. It all depends on what, exactly, you need.

Comment: @Tomáš'GunsBlazing'Frček You're welcome. I didn't mean to disagree with Thirisangu. I was just typing my answer while he was (just slower :) and automatically chose `Descendants`. As I said - whatever suits you best.